# Changing View's layout_column and layout_row attribute in java

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

My current Textview's layout_column and layout_row attribute values are 0 and 0, respectively. I wish to change the layout_column and layout_row to 1 and 1, using java. I was wondering how I can accomplish this. Also, my textview are children to the gridlayout.

Comment: What you mean by TextView's layoutcolumn and row?? Textview doesn't have those attribures.Please post your code to make us understand better.

Comment: <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/target_00"
            android:layout_width="18pt"
            android:layout_height="18pt"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@android:color/white"

Comment: I want to change :

Comment: android:layout_column="0"  and android:layout_row="0"  dynamically using java

Comment: gridview.setNumColumns(number); using will change dynamically change columns only If you want change grdivew not textview. I don't think textview has rows and columns